# Validation error on USCIS website while checking H1B case status

Tags: h1-visa, application-status

I want to check updates on my petition but I am getting a validation error.

Am I checking at correct place https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/mycasestatus.do?

Is this error common, nothing to worry about or do I need to inform employer (petitioner)?

Comment: I have the same issue, my attorney sent me the receipt notice so I am sure that the number is accurate. Did you ever find out what is the issue.

Comment: Even I was able to view my status when I created an account. For some reason it works that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try registering here (check the below url) and adding ur receipt number. That worked for me. https://myaccount.uscis.dhs.gov/

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. Can you also answer https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/how-long-is-i-797c-h-1b-receipt-valid ??

Answer (score 3):

Validation Error(s)
You must correct the following error(s) before proceeding:

> My Case Status does not recognize the receipt number entered. Please check your receipt number and try again. If you need further assistance, please call the USCIS Contact Center at 1-800-375-5283.

So if there are any issues you should call the number shown above

Answer (score 1):

This may be just a technical glitch with which URL to use.  Try this: go to the main page https://www.uscis.gov then go to Tools -> Case Status Online, then put in your case number, then click Check Status.

Edit:

- Otherwise, you may have entered the number incorrectly. Be sure it's exactly the same as on the Form I-797 Receipt Notice. (Be really sure of this. It's easy to get nervous about your immigration petition, and then you can make a simple mistake that you wouldn't normally make.)
- Otherwise, there may be some problem on USCIS's side, which might be important or unimportant.  If the problem persists for more than a few days it would be a good idea to check first with your employer or lawyer, and then either you or they work with USCIS to identify the problem.

Comment: This is what I am doing, this how I went to the link that I shared. It is still showing error.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error? For example, if I put in a bogus receipt number, I get "Validation Error(s)
You must correct the following error(s) before proceeding:
My Case Status does not recognize the receipt number entered. Please check your receipt number and try again. If you need further assistance, please call the USCIS Contact Center at 1-800-375-5283."

Comment: This is the same error what I am getting. When I called there, it was a very poor reception/connection. After talking(barely) she transferred the call, where they promised to call on the same number but I was calling from skype So I think I wont get any call.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct case number as shown on Form I-797?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure.