# How long is I-797C H-1B receipt valid?

Tags: h1-visa

I have got my name selected in 2018 H-1B lottery results, but unfortunately, the current employer doesn't have any suitable job for me in its USA location.

Should I push them to assign a suitable job to me ASAP or can I wait? 
Would my lottery expire?  I mean would I have to apply again in the 2019 lottery? If not, how long does it remain valid?

Comment: The lottery is for H-1B start dates on or near October 1, filed on or near April 1. I think you can only avoid the lottery in future years if you at least begin H-1B work as scheduled on or near October 1.  But I'm not sure of this.